# Convergence in distribution and moments

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

Let us assume that we are given real random variables $X_n$ that converge in distribution to $X$. Moreover, it is known that $\sup_n \mathbb{E}[g(X_n)] < \infty$, where $g$ is a measurable function which is not bounded.

Clearly, if $\mathbb{E}[g(X)] < \infty$ the theorem of bounded convergence ensures that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E}(X_n) = \mathbb{E}[X]$.

However, I am asking myself whether $\mathbb{E}[g(X)] < \infty$ is really necessary in the above statement. That is, is it possible to infer that $\mathbb{E}[g(X)] < \infty$ from the fact that $\sup_n \mathbb{E}[g(X_n)] < \infty$ and $X_n \to^d X$?

(Probably this does not help, but the sequence $X_n$ describes an ergodic Markov chain with a countably infinite state space.)

It would be great if someone could help me out or point me to a reference.

Best wishes,
Max